# Android - Easy/comfortable way to design DrawerLayout using Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, drawerlayout

In my app I have implementer the `DrawerLayout` for one of the activities, and added a `listView` in the center of the activity. In order to add items (`Button`s and `textView` etc..) I add them manually by editing the XML layout file (by adding raw attributes to the page). Is there any way to design the drawer in Android Studio just like you design a simple `Activity`? I added a screen shot of how it looks in my Studio, all the elements appear on the left of the page, outside of the emulator.

[image: DrawerLayout design AndroidStudio]

EDIT: Here is my XML layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The first child in the layout is for the main Activity UI-->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            android:background="#ffffffff">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/listViewChat"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawerContainer"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start"
            android:background="@drawable/splash_background_blur"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:clickable="true">

            <!--this custom view serves as a dimmer for the drawer-->
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#73000000"
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:maxLength="15"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:hint="Enter user name"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:text="@string/buttonSelectPhoto"
                android:id="@+id/buttonTakePhoto"
                android:background="@drawable/splash_button"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:text="@string/buttonTakePhoto"
                android:id="@+id/buttonSelectPhoto"
                android:background="@drawable/splash_button"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:text="@string/buttonTakeATour"
                android:id="@+id/buttonTakeTour"
                android:background="@drawable/splash_button"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"/>

            <!-- <ListView
                 android:id="@+id/navList"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            <LinearLayout android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="0px" />-->

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

EDIT

I split the content of the drawer into a separate `xml` file and tried to add this content using the `<include>` tag. When I click on the "hamburger" (open drawer) icon the app crashes with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT` error. What is wrong with my layout?

The activity which utilizes the `DrawerLayout` and `include`s the new stand alone layout (drawer content):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The first child in the layout is for the main Activity UI-->
    <include layout="@layout/drawer_layout_and_content"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="#ffffffff">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listViewChat"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here's the custom layout which is used as the drawer in the main activity:
 (drawer_layout_and_content.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_background_blur"
    android:id="@+id/drawerContainer">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#73000000"
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="@string/buttonSelectPhoto"
        android:id="@+id/buttonTakePhoto"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_button"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout xml please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `include` key word to do that. First, create a layout file called `drawer_content.xml`, then do `<include layout="@layout/drawer_content">`. Then you code `drawer_content.xml` just like a layout file of an `Activity` or a `Fragment`. And if you want to know more details, check [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html).

Comment: Sounds interesting. You mean, I need to create a `RelativeLayout` as a stand alone xml file, place all my desired content inside it, and then, <i>just</i> `include` it inside the `DrawerLayout` of my choice?

Comment: @undroid yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to separate this into a stand alone `drawer` layout which is included in my main activity, I get an exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT`. Could you please take a look at the content i've just added to the original post?

Comment: Should this be declared in the Manifest somehow?

Comment: you should set `android:layout_gravity="left|start"` in the root view of your `drawer_layout_and_content`.